can not run abp io api just giving me error redis not working but i did install resis via wsl
i am faceing an issue when i create abp io project and run it. it sayes that redis is not present. but i did install redis in my windows 11 os via wsl. still this api refuse to run and give me same error that redis is not present
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log, Nullable`1 serverType, EndPointCollection endpoints)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log)
   at Acme.BookStore.BookStoreHttpApiHostModule.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<ConfigureDistributedLocking>b__0(IServiceProvider sp) in E:\dotnet\Acme.BookStore\aspnet-core\src\Acme.BookStore.HttpApi.Host\BookStoreHttpApiHostModule.cs:line 152
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacRegistration.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Register>b__1(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__2_0(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DelegateMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext context)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext context)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)

i tried to disable redis server via appsettings but its not worked
"Redis": {
  "IsEnabled": "false",
  "Configuration": "127.0.0.1"
},


Do you have started redis ? you can also use a redis docker container for local development https://redis.io/docs/install/install-stack/docker/

You can also install RedisInsights app from redis, and try and connect to your redis instance with it. If does not connect, then you know that your instance is not properly exposed to your abp server. I would recommend just using docker and installing redis, this is easier to maintain.
